# Pinecript : how can I get the max value of all the sma with length between 1 and i?

Tags: for-loop, max, moving-average, pine-script

I'm trying to write a script which would return the highest value of any moving average whose length is between 1 and a specified number i.e something that would work like this :
maxMA = max(sma(close,1), ... , sma(close,i))
Is there a way to do this ??

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

Like you did, using the [`max()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_max) function. It can take up to 10 arguments. If you need more, just use the max of multiple max results.

---

#### Version 2

[2020.03.27 10:18 — LucF]

To return the highest of a bunch of sma's of different periods, you can use:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
n = input(50)
samples = input(true)

Sma(src,p) => a = cum(src), (a - a[max(p,0)])/max(p,0)
mx = 0.
for i = 1 to n
    mx := max(mx, Sma(close, i))
plot(mx, "", color.gray, 2)

plot(samples ? Sma(close, 1) : na)
plot(samples ? Sma(close, n / 2) : na)
plot(samples ? Sma(close, n / 3) : na)
plot(samples ? Sma(close, n / 4) : na)
plot(samples ? Sma(close, n / 5) : an)
```

Note this requires an MA function that will return correct results in a `for` loop, which many won`t. The function used here is lifted from the alexgrover functions [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But maybe I wasn't clear enough : what I want is to be able to get the max value of all the sma between 1 and i, i being an input that could go up to I don't know, maybe 50 or above... I tried to do it with a for loop, like from i=1 to i=maxlength, hma:=max(sma(src, i),sma(src,i+1)), ...... but it only compare 2 consecutive values. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sry. Had misunderstood. Added a v2 of the answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !